# Forma Abaloada com CSS como fazer? Como fazer um shape nesse formato meio aredondado?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu gostaria de fazer com que um elemento fique meio arredondado, ele não é um elipse, nem um círculo, e nem um elemento com `border-radius`. Ele é uma forma meio arredondada como podem ver na imagem abaixo e que não consegui fazer com CSS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei chegar nessa forma abaloada, mas não consegui, ele ainda fica um uma parta reta em cada um dos lados. eu gostaria que cada um dos lados ficasse curvado bem como nessa imagem de referencia.

Segue meu código.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(231, 247, 255);
}
.box {
    width: 155px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    border-radius: 45%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**OBS:** ***Sei que com SVG eu consigo, mas minha intenção é que seja apenas com CSS***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe a propriedade CSS [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) que você pode usar para cortar partes indesejadas do background do elemento.

[Este artigo do CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#article-header-id-3) tem uns exemplos legais para entender como a propriedade funciona.

Para definir um *shape* complexo você pode:

- Usar o [`path()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape#path()) que recebe como parâmetro um string contendo um path no mesmo formato do path SVG.

  ```
  clip-path: path("M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10");
  ```
- Usar um [ClipPath SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) e referenciá-lo no CSS.

  ```
  clip-path: url("#meu-clip");
  ```

Abaixo é o path da sua imagem vetorizado que utilizarei nos exemplos:

```
m59.533456,149.455558c-16.519209,-1.510568 -33.831918,-7.984429 -41.622636,-15.609198c-24.814882,-24.169081 -23.227884,-99.913255 2.452634,-119.694497c11.686078,-8.991474 31.018602,-13.810903 55.256394,-13.810903c19.548933,0 32.605601,2.445681 44.796633,8.344088c15.437165,7.480906 23.30002,20.140901 27.988878,45.101232c1.731271,9.423064 1.731271,33.37635 -0.072136,43.302937c-1.514862,8.559883 -5.338085,20.50056 -8.512082,26.54283c-3.390405,6.401929 -11.181124,13.882835 -18.25048,17.479425c-12.118896,6.258066 -26.257608,8.919542 -46.239359,8.703746c-7.141492,-0.071932 -14.210848,-0.215795 -15.797846,-0.359659z
```

### Exemplos

#### path()

```css
body {
  background-color: #eedddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.quadrado {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(#3ce092, #3b91b7);
  clip-path: path("m59.533456,149.455558c-16.519209,-1.510568 -33.831918,-7.984429 -41.622636,-15.609198c-24.814882,-24.169081 -23.227884,-99.913255 2.452634,-119.694497c11.686078,-8.991474 31.018602,-13.810903 55.256394,-13.810903c19.548933,0 32.605601,2.445681 44.796633,8.344088c15.437165,7.480906 23.30002,20.140901 27.988878,45.101232c1.731271,9.423064 1.731271,33.37635 -0.072136,43.302937c-1.514862,8.559883 -5.338085,20.50056 -8.512082,26.54283c-3.390405,6.401929 -11.181124,13.882835 -18.25048,17.479425c-12.118896,6.258066 -26.257608,8.919542 -46.239359,8.703746c-7.141492,-0.071932 -14.210848,-0.215795 -15.797846,-0.359659z");
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrado"></div>
```

Vale lembrar que o [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) é experimental, então o [suporte é bem baixo](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

O exemplo acima funciona no Firefox 64 ativando a *flag*:

```
layout.css.clip-path-path.enabled
```

---

#### SVG

```css
body {
  background-color: #eedddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.quadrado {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(#3ce092, #3b91b7);
  clip-path: url("#tela-tv-tubo");
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrado"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="tela-tv-tubo">
      <path d="m59.533456,149.455558c-16.519209,-1.510568 -33.831918,-7.984429 -41.622636,-15.609198c-24.814882,-24.169081 -23.227884,-99.913255 2.452634,-119.694497c11.686078,-8.991474 31.018602,-13.810903 55.256394,-13.810903c19.548933,0 32.605601,2.445681 44.796633,8.344088c15.437165,7.480906 23.30002,20.140901 27.988878,45.101232c1.731271,9.423064 1.731271,33.37635 -0.072136,43.302937c-1.514862,8.559883 -5.338085,20.50056 -8.512082,26.54283c-3.390405,6.401929 -11.181124,13.882835 -18.25048,17.479425c-12.118896,6.258066 -26.257608,8.919542 -46.239359,8.703746c-7.141492,-0.071932 -14.210848,-0.215795 -15.797846,-0.359659z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: O SVG sei que poderia resolver o caso, mas minha intenção ainda é conseguir com CSS ... se for possível...

Comment: Se eu conseguir converter o `<path>` para css `poligon` eu consigo retirar.. atualiza assim que descobrir um jeito

Comment: Arrumei outra forma.... e vc não vai acreditar :D http://prntscr.com/lx7q1u amavou publicar!

Answer (score 5):

**Opção 1**

Com apenas uma div e seus pseudo-elementos `::after` e `::before` é possível chegar em um resultado bem fiel a imagem de referência.

A ideia é ter uma `div` principal como *container*. Depois no elemento `::before` criamos um `linear-gradiente` que sera a nossa cor de fundo. E posteriormente vamos colocar um `border-radius` nesse `::before` apenas para fazer um ajuste fina na curvatura dos vértices.

O segundo passo é com o `::after`. Aqui é o ponto principal, pois o `::after` vai receber **DOIS** `radial-gradiente`, um na vertical e outro na horizontal, esses gradientes começam da cor `transarente` para a cor de fundo que no caso e branco. Como o `::after` fica por cima do `::before` ele vai funcionar como uma máscara.

Para ajudar a entender deixo esse diagrama.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o `border-radius` foi aplicado no `::before` para fazer o ajuste fino nos cantos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Esse é o resultado final, ainda dando uma margem para ajustes :D**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código referente a imagem acima. ***Deixe os comentários no código de onde fazer os ajustes.***

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.box {
    height: 21.5vw;
    width: 22vw;
    position: relative;
}
.box::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to top, #2196F3 20%,#3CDE92 80%);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 170% 230%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
/* controla o ajuste fino nos cantos */
    border-radius:46%;
}
.box::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
/* cor da mascara deve ser igual a cor do fundo */
    background-image: radial-gradient( transparent 38%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 39%), radial-gradient( transparent 38%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 39%);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 170% 230%, 230% 170%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**OBS:** A limitação é que a cor da mascara feita com o `radial-gradiente` do `::after` deve ser a mesma cor de fundo, deve ser uma cor sólida de preferência...

---

**Opção 2**

Essa acho que ainda não é o modelo perfeito, mas é uma opção com o fator `crossbrowser` bem melhor. Ela é feita com 2 *pseudos-elementos* `::after` e `::before` em uma `div` e `linear-gradient`. Também precisei usa transforme para tentar deixa o mais próximo da imagem de referência. Também precise colocar essa `div` dentro de um *container*, apenas para fazer um ajuste fino de `transform: scaleY(.95)` para tentar ficar mais fiel a imagem base.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz o modelo tratado ao lado de um circulo completo com `border-radius: 50%` e outro com `border-radius: 45%`, a diferença é sutil, mas achei que valia a penda deixar a resposta ai.

Segue o código do modelo acima

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scaleY(.95);
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 41%;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg,#3CDE92, #3B92B7);
}
.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#3CDE92, #3B92B7);
  transform: scaleX(1.1) rotate(-45deg);
}
.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#3CDE92, #3B92B7);
  transform: scaleY(1.1) rotate(-45deg);
}
.controle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
  border-radius: 45%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#3CDE92, #3B92B7);
  transform: translateX(120px);
}
.bola {
  position: absolute;
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#3CDE92, #3B92B7);
  transform: translateX(-120px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bola"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="controle"></div>
```

Comment: Caramba, se puxou com essa opção 1!

Comment: @fernandosavio aqui o bagulho é loko! 